# To get an organisation name and abbreviate it, with variations which omit the words 'of' and 'and' but also include it in other variations

Tags: php, arrays, string, algorithm

I need to get the organisation name provided to me as a string in PHP and abbreviate it using the first letter of each word in that same order. If there are words like 'of' or 'and', I need to show the abbreviations with or without including those two words' first letters. Also, I need to omit duplicate abbreviations.

```php
    <?php

function splort($org){
        $org_arr = explode(' ',$org);
        $abbr1 = '';
        $abbr2 = '';
    $abbr_arr = array();
        foreach($org_arr as $word){
              $abbr1 .= $word[0];
              if(strtolower($word) == 'of')
                    continue;
              $abbr2 .= $word[0];
        }
        if($abbr1 == $abbr2) array_push($abbr_arr,$abbr1);
        else  array_push($abbr_arr,$abbr1,$abbr2);
        return $abbr_arr;
     }

     print_r(splort("State Bank of India"));
```

The above code manages for only one word, i.e. 'of'. I need to take care of the word 'and' too. The above code produces only two variations, which is expected. 'SBoI' and 'SBI'.

If the organisation name is 'State Bank of and India', the following should be the possible abbreviations:
SBI
SBoI
SBaI
SBoaI

**Update**

I was also assigned the task of returning the first three letters of an organization name if it consists of only word. I should also return all the separate words in an organization.

I formed this code before this question was answered, because it had been put on hold. Please take a look and suggest improvements.

```php
<?php

function split_and_shorten($org){

    $org_t = trim($org);
    $org_arr = explode(" ", $org_t);

    if(count($org_arr) > 1){
                $abbr1 = "";
                $abbr2 = "";
                $abbr3 = "";
                $abbr4 = "";
                foreach($org_arr as $word){
                        $abbr1 .= $word[0];
                        if (strtolower($word) != 'of')
                $abbr2 .= $word[0];
            if (strtolower($word) != 'and')
                $abbr3 .= $word[0];
            if (strtolower($word) == 'of' || strtolower($word) == 'and')
                continue;
            $abbr4 .= $word[0];
                }
        array_push($org_arr, $abbr1, $abbr2, $abbr3, $abbr4);
    }

    else {
        $short = substr($org_arr[0], 0, 3);
        array_push($org_arr, $short);
    }

    return array_unique($org_arr);
}

print_r(split_and_shorten("State Bank of and India"));
```

Output:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => State
    [1] => Bank
    [2] => of
    [3] => and
    [4] => India
    [5] => SBoaI
    [6] => SBaI
    [7] => SBoI
    [8] => SBI
)
```

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried?

Comment: @Alon Eitan please put this question off hold

Comment: @KrishPG Done. One more vote to reopen it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that will do what you want. It takes a string of words and a list of stopwords. If a word is not a stopword, its initial gets added to each abbreviation in the list. If it is a stopword, the list of abbreviations is duplicated, with the new ones getting the initial of the stopword added to them.

```
function splort($org, $stop_words) {
    $words = explode(' ', $org);
    $abbrevs = array('');
    foreach ($words as $word) {
        if (in_array($word, $stop_words)) {
            // create a new set of abbreviations with this word's initial included
            $new_abbrevs = array();
            foreach ($abbrevs as $abbrev) {
                $new_abbrevs[] = $abbrev . $word[0];
            }
            // merge the arrays
            $abbrevs = array_merge($abbrevs, $new_abbrevs);
       }
        else {
            // add the initial to each abbreviation
            foreach ($abbrevs as &$abb) {
                $abb .= $word[0];
            }
        }
    }
    return $abbrevs;
}

$stop_words = array('of', 'and');
print_r(splort('State Bank of and India', $stop_words));
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => SBI
    [1] => SBoI
    [2] => SBaI
    [3] => SBoaI
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/QgUlp)

Comment: Genius! I am not able to understand your code fully, but it works! Also, you have managed for any number of stop words. It would be helpful if you can comment in detail, so that a novice like me can understand what's going on. Thank You

Comment: @KrishPG basically the code cycles through the words in `$org`, looking for stop words (in the `$stop_words` array). Every time a stop word is encountered, you have to double the number of possible abbreviations (since you will have one set with the initial of the stop word, and one without. The set with the initial is created in `$new_abbrevs` and then that is merged with `$abbrevs` to give us the set of abbreviations with and without the stopword. If the word is a normal word, its initial is just added to the current set of abbreviations. Hope that helps!